# How to iterate over a changing vector in Matlab, not consecutive number?

Tags: matlab, vector, literate-programming

I am really a beginner level at matlab. Now I want to have a loop, such that it iterates over a vector (not consecutive numbers) which contains a decreasing number of elements through iteration.

For example, I have `[1; 2 ;3; 4]` (thinking of it as person 1, 2, 3, 4)
then I want to do something such that for example person 1 and 4 gets food, person 2 and 3 left with no food.

In the next round, I want person 2 and 3 (those unassigned)to go through the assignment process again but not 1 and 4. 
So I create a vector [2;3] to keep track of those left without food.

However,the `for i=1:length(vector)` gives me a series of consecutive numbers, what I want is

`for i in vector do something; end`

How to implement this?

when I just put

```
i=vector,
```

Matlab says Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to loop through an arbitrary vector, just use that vector directly in a for loop. For example:

```
vector = [3, 4, 7, 1, 1]

for i = vector
    disp(i)
end
```

will output `3  4  7  1  1`. This is the equivalent of "for i in vector do something."

Answer (score 1):

`for i=1:length(vector)` is giving you an index into the vector - it will always be consecutive because it represents the `first..last` position of the vector.

It sounds like you want to get an identifier *out* of the vector. You can do this within your existing loop: `id=vector[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Matlab structs?

```
s = struct(field1,value1,...,fieldN,valueN)
```

You can have an array 'people' of structs (of type person) which you can loop through...

```
for i=1:length(people)
    if people(i).HasBeenFeed = False
        % feed this person...
    end
end
```